# Sandbox solution disabled in office 365 - what is the best alternate for custom workflow actions

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-apps, sandbox-solution

I have some more than 10 workflow custom actions created and using those in 2010 workflow. but my site is o365 site. Now sandbox solution is disabled, what is the best way to convert my codes and use that again in 2010 workflow?

Few say go for Client side code and App model. but what exactly we can do with that ? If i have 2013 workflow i can create webservice and call that method from my 2013 workflow so no problem. but i have lot of 2010 workflows already running and most of them are using complex custom actions.

So I can't convert my 2010 workflow to 2013 workflow, but want to call my custom actions now, thats it. Anyone have faced this problem or have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

The way we handled that was with SharePoint provider hosted add-in, SharePoint 2013 workflows and custom API Endpoints (the custom code).
This way our workflows are all only with standard things only doing http call for the custom parts.
However this might not be the best anser for non-developers.
For these cases I suggest you look at Azure Functions and Microsoft Flow.
Hope that helps